# Can't call App Script function thru the REST api

Tags: java, google-apps-script, http-status-code-404, google-apps-script-api

I'm using Java API for calling the AppScript function on the spreadsheet
When I list deployments

```
List<Deployment> deployments = projects.deployments().list("XXX").execute().getDeployments();
```

I can see my deployments but the deployment.getFunctionSet() is NULL
So when I call

```
Operation op = service.scripts().run(
            "XXX",
            new ExecutionRequest().setDevMode(true).setFunction("exportJson")
).execute();
```

I get

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

The question - how to call function from the google app script? )

Comment: See if [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api+http-status-code-404) help

Comment: Have you tried to deploy first your script as API executable: On AppsScript -> your script -> publish -> Deploy as API executable.

Comment: Yes, and I can see those deploys in the deployments() list

Comment: I have tested the api with your code, and without the `setDevMode(true)` it's working. Can you verify it?